# Firefox can't read or write to directories symlinked across partitions

Tags: partitioning, permissions, firefox, symbolic-link

Using Ubuntu 22.04, I installed firefox from the mozillateam ppa (current installed version is 118.0.1). I have data stored on `/dev/sda1`, mounted as `/data`, and Ubuntu 22.04 installed on `/dev/nvme0n1p2`. The data on `sda1` is accessed via symlinks. When I use Firefox to save to, or read from, a directory symlinked from `/dev/sda1`, I get these errors:

- saving: `The file could not be saved because you do not have the proper permissions.  Choose another save directory.`
- reading: `The following files couldn't be attached: foo.zip. Please try again later.`

I have not found any other application (including Chrome and Edge) that has this limitation. I'm trying to figure out if there is a security setting in firefox responsible for this or if there is something in my configuration to take a look at.

Firefox works fine with directories symlinked within the install partition.

**Update**: Responding to @vanadium I confirmed that the deb version of Firefox is running --- System monitor shows the process is `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox`. However I notice that `Security Context` is `firefox (enforce)`. For both Emacs and Chrome, `Security Context` is `unconfined`. I'm guessing this is the issue? If so, exactly what does this mean and how can it be changed?

Comment: First thing to check are permissions of the destination. Second thing to check is that you are sure it is still a deb version of firefox running. The snap version will exhibit the limitation you now describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was apparmor. I've never used apparmor before, but I have to assume that the mozillateam ppa package creates a security profile for firefox. I can't imagine how else it got there. This caused my problem. I solved it with

```
sudo aa-complain /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

Thank you chatGPT :-) This apparently logs "errors" rather than enforcing the security controls.

For anyone else having this problem, you need to install `apparmor-utils` in order to obtain `aa-complain`.